# split xpath string by axes expression

Tags: java, string, xpath

I have XPath like this:

```
something1/something2/AXES::tag/something3...
```

where AXES is limited set of words:

- child
- attribute
- ...

so I have to split this xpath into three parts:

1. something1/somthing2/
2. AXES::tag
3. something3...

How can I do this?
I realize it easy, but it should work as fast as possible.

---

my solution(Of course it is it is not optimal):

```
private static String[] splitForFirstAxes(String s){
    String[] a = new String[3];
    int i = s.indexOf("::",0);
    if (0 > i ) return null;
    String part1 = s.substring(0, i);
    String part2 = s.substring(i+2);
    int part1LastsSlash = part1.lastIndexOf('/');
    int part2FirstSlash = part2.indexOf('/');
    a[0] = part1.substring(0, part1LastsSlash);// First part
    a[2] = part2.substring(part2FirstSlash+1);// Second part
    a[1] = part1.substring(part1LastsSlash+1) +"::" +part2.substring(0,part2FirstSlash);// Axes
    return a;
}
```

Comment: If it's so easy: where is your solution?

Comment: String.split() is a very helpful tool in these types of situations.

Comment: Jlordo, I have added my solution. :)

Comment: @yaroslavTir: And I have added mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String xpath = "something1/something2/AXES::tag/something3";
String[] parts = xpath.split("/");
```

Access each part by its index:

```
System.out.println(parts[0] + parts[1]);
System.out.println(parts[2]);
System.out.println(parts[3]);
```

Results:

```
something1something2
AXES::tag
something3
```

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you are looking for:

```
String input = "something1/something2/AXES::tag/something3...";
String[] tokens = input.split("/");
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (token.contains("::")) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            resultList.add(sb.append("/").toString());
        }
        resultList.add(token);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    } else {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("/");
        }
        sb.append(token);
    }
} 
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    resultList.add(sb.toString());
}
System.out.println(resultList);
```

Output:

```
[something1/something2/, AXES::tag, something3...]
```

Comment: I guess split is very expensive operation

Comment: I promise you, this will not be the bottleneck of your application. Also, guessing is always bad. Show me some facts...

Comment: @yaroslavTir: Also, my method can handle any input, whereas yours will crash for different wrong inputs...